# How to round chartjs bar corners in Angular?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, charts

I'm trying to round my chartjs bar, but I can't get it...

I'm using Angular 11 and 2.9.4 chartjs version.

This is my component, where I create the chart:

```
export class StatisticsComponent implements OnInit {

  barChartOptionsAllTime: ChartOptions = {};
  barChartLabelsAllTime: Label[] = [];
  barChartTypeAllTime: ChartType = 'bar';
  barChartLegendAllTime = false;
  barChartPluginsAllTime = [];

  barChartDataAllTime: ChartDataSets[] = [
    {
      data: [],
      borderWidth: 2,
      backgroundColor: "rgba(0, 170, 228, .5)",
      hoverBackgroundColor: "rgba(2, 147, 196)",
      borderColor: 'rgb(0, 103, 138)',
      hoverBorderColor: "rgb(0, 103, 138)",
      lineTension: .1,
      radius: 20
    }
  ];

  constructor(private databaseService: DatabaseService) {
    this.getstatistics();
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
  }

  async getstatistics() {
    await this.databaseService.getStatisticsPlacesAllTime()
      .then(resp => {
        let maxCounter = 0;
        for (const statistics of resp) {
          this.barChartLabelsAllTime.push(statistics.title);
          this.barChartDataAllTime[0].data?.push(statistics.quantity);

          if (statistics.quantity > maxCounter) maxCounter = statistics.quantity;
        }

        this.barChartOptionsAllTime = this.createBarChartOptions(this.barChartOptionsAllTime, maxCounter)
      })
      .catch(err => {
        $("#errorModalMessage").html(keys.error_modal_message_2);
        $('#errorModal').modal('show');
      });
  }

  createBarChartOptions(barChartOptions: ChartOptions, maxYAxes: number): ChartOptions {
    barChartOptions = {
      responsive: true,
      scales: {
        yAxes: [{
          ticks: {
            stepSize: 1,
            min: 0,
            max: maxYAxes + 1
          }
        }]
      }
    }

    return barChartOptions;
  }
}
```

I'm using *radius*, but it does not work...

I don't know if this is possible with 2.9.4 chartjs version, I know that in the lastest version it is.

Comment: Hi, Will it be possible for you to share your code sample on Stackblitz. That would be really helpful

Comment: Sorry, I think it would be this link: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-kvdstg?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html

Comment: Workaround will be to give border radius to the canvas element.

Comment: I think so... Thanks

Comment: did you got solution ?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you should use "borderRadius" instead of just "radius".

Comment: It works in the newest version, but this is the 2.9.4 version.

Comment: @JuanGracia according to docs https://www.chartjs.org/docs/2.7.3/charts/bar.html there is no radius property and because it's a canvas, you can't use CSS. You can try to write a directive that will update this chart but it isn't a good approach because you can simply update your library.